# Multiple aggregates in SQL query

Tags: sql, db2

Please help me wrap my head around subqueries (assuming that's what is needed here). I have a table of **orders** and **customers**. I'm looking to write a query that shows me both the number of orders for all customers AND the number of orders for customers with a specific profile.

```
select count(o.order_no) from orders o
where o.order_dt = '20200320'
```

and

```
select count(o.order_no) from orders o
left join customers c on o.cust_no = c.cust_no
where o.order_dt = '20200320' and c.cust_prfl in ('C', 'D')
```

So I'm looking for two aggregate values at the same time - first the number of orders for set date and then also the same aggregate, but with the additional condition of customers with specific profile. Hence the result should be:

**3   2**

Additional monkey wrench I have is that I'd even like the count of **customer** table to be included `select count(c.cust_prfl) from customers c where c.cust_prfl in ('C', 'D', 'E')` but that's less of an issue. But in an ideal scenario I'd have **3 2 3**

I can't really utilize the `union` command to connect separate queries, since I need the result in different columns, not rows.

```
ORDERS
Order_no   Order_dt   Cust_no
101        20200303     1
102        20200320     3
103        20200320     3
104        20200320     2

CUSTOMERS
Cust_no    Cust_prfl
1          A
2          B
3          C
4          C
5          D
```

Comment: Why are you using a LEFT JOIN in the second query?  Are you sure you need it?

Comment: I do need it to join CUSTOMERS table, so that I could filter out orders made by customers with Cust_prfl C & D. As customer on order no 104 has Cust_prfl B, it is excluded from the result.

Comment: Yes, you need a join.  Why do you need a LEFT OUTER JOIN?  Why wouldn't a regular inner join do the same job?

Comment: I'm not a seasoned SQL user, so LEFT JOIN has become my go-to for some reason. But I guess INNER JOIN would work too in this instance. What are the considerations for preferring INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN (other than INNER JOIN perhaps being a "default" JOIN function)? Better performance?

Comment: Fundamentally, yes, better performance. The optimizer has to do things differently if it is processing a LEFT JOIN in case one of the rows from the table on the LHS of the join isn't matched by any rows from the table on the RHS of the join.  If there's never a mismatch, it may be able to reorder the query processing so it does less work; sometimes dramatically less work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your original requirement with conditional aggregation over your existing query (although just using a `JOIN` rather than a `LEFT JOIN` since presumably all orders must have existing customers):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS orders,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Cust_prfl IN ('C', 'D') THEN 1 END) AS orders_cust
FROM (
  SELECT o.order_dt, c.Cust_prfl
  FROM orders o
  JOIN customers c ON c.Cust_no = o.Cust_no
  WHERE o.order_dt = '20200320'  
) o
```

To get the total number of customers with the different profiles requires a separate subquery, but you can add that to this query too:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS orders,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Cust_prfl IN ('C', 'D') THEN 1 END) AS orders_cust,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE Cust_prfl IN ('C', 'D', 'E')) AS cde_customers
FROM (
  SELECT o.order_dt, c.Cust_prfl
  FROM orders o
  JOIN customers c ON c.Cust_no = o.Cust_no
  WHERE o.order_dt = '20200320'  
) o
```

Output:

```
orders  orders_cust     cde_customers
3       2               3
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ccda2/7)

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood you question Joey112, below are the two queries.

1) With this query you can get all data

```sql
select o.order_no, o.order_dt, c.cust_no, c.cust_prfl
from orders o
  left join customers c
    on o.cust_no = c.cust_no
```

2) Here you are applying just where conditions

```sql
select o.order_no, o.order_dt, c.cust_no, c.cust_prfl
from orders o
  left join customers c
    on o.cust_no = c.cust_no
where o.order_dt = '20200320' and c.cust_prfl in ('C', 'D')
```

Comment: Those don't seem to be producing counts as requested.  The desired answer is either `3 2` or `3 2 3` (you don't seem to address the third query at all).

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I'm looking for double COUNT function (one with just date in the WHERE clause and the other with both date and cust_prfl in the WHERE clause)